# Update Composable State Across activity boundaries

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata

I'm building a android application, that has multiple activities that share a data model.

The data model is composed of two layers:

- The first stores a list of objects to be used, and methods for saving this to disk.
- One abstracts the first, to prevent me from erasing my data again.

The abstraction is stored on the application class to allow all activities access to it.
(This is needed to access some of the android apis for saving to files)

I then have two more more activities, that will display this data in a list.

The activities each have their own view models, that access these abstractions throughb the app class.

The view models are used to add and read these changes.

when one activity changes adds items to the list, i need the other to also update their views.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

So far i've tried a couple of methods

- Working with recycler view works because of the adapter having an update function. But this doesn't work with compose
- i've tried setting up mutable state in the model and copying that to each activity. which isn't what that is meant to be used for. It also doesn't work.
- Ive added Live data to the model then used a MediatorLiveData to propagate it, This almost works by the ui doesn't catch this.

Comment: I would recommend you read https://dev.to/zachklipp/two-mutables-dont-make-a-right-2kgp as this might cover what you are running into. If not, can you update this with a code example of what doesn't work for you, broad questions like this are difficult to answer as your are clearly having an issue but exact issue you are having is difficult to determine from your description. Code examples would clear this up.

Comment: Thanks @chuckj, i'll have a read through the article and update the question if it doesnt solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @chuckj, I read over the article https://dev.to/zachklipp/two-mutables-dont-make-a-right-2kgp and it stated that setting the state of a observable, with the same **object** won't update it.

So by cloning the list using `List.toList()` it creates a new object that can be set to the live data, and thus a new object.